# Error after updating from 0.8.3 to 0.9.2

Tags: meteor

I've updated from 0.8.3 to the latest version (0.9.2) and I've received this error. I have gone so far as to create a new meteor (0.9.2) project, and transfer all of my code from the old project, then freshly install all packages required.

```
/Users/nathaniel/Desktop/ESOS/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2682
throw err;                                                                
      ^
ReferenceError: Router is not defined
    at app/common/router.js:1:36
    at app/common/router.js:177:3
    at /Users/nathaniel/Desktop/ESOS/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/nathaniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.31.sw6o3m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/nathaniel/Desktop/ESOS/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 7
```

Comment: Make sure the iron-router package installed is "iron:router" and not anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. I installed iron:core, thinking it included iron:router. Thanks.